# Obtaining distribution of results from LCIA

Tags: brightway

I would like the distribution for the impact of ecoinvent processes, using one of the existing impact assessment methods, doing Monte Carlo simulations.  Is there an example notebook or instructions on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to do it (for a random activity and method):

`from brightway2 import *`
`import numpy as np`
`ecoinvent = Database("ecoinvent 3.2 cutoff")`

The MonteCarlo class derives from the LCA class, and is instantiated just like an LCA object.
`my_MC = MonteCarloLCA({ecoinvent.random():1}, methods.random())`

Say you want to obtain 1000 samples:
`iterations = 1000`

You can create an empty numpy array to collect the results:
`scores = np.zeros([1, iterations])`

Then, you calculate scores using `next` on your object:

```
for iteration in range(1000):
    next(my_MC)
    scores[0, iteration] = my_MC.score
```

In this example, this will be a numpy array with 1000 elements. You can then analyse this array with whatever statistical modules you are at ease with.

There are several other Monte Carlo based classes, allowing other functionalities. Have a look at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-calc/src/662740694a8c70074105b5dca45b58651adb5eb5/bw2calc/monte_carlo.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), you may find something useful.

Comment: when I tried running the code you provided I got the following error: "NameError: name 'MonteCarlo' is not defined". The "MonteCarlo" class does not seem to be defined in the source code you referenced. The "Getting Started" example for Brightway2 (https://brightwaylca.org/examples/getting-started.html)  uses "MonteCarloLCA" for the class, and this seemed to work with the code you provided. Do you have a recommendation about which class to use or how to make "MonteCarlo" a defined class?

Comment: Thanks @Calvin, the Class name is indeed MonteCarloLCA.